# Cassandra NumberFormatException: Zero length BigInteger

Tags: c#, database, cassandra, cql

> Unable to execute CQL script on 'connection1': com.datastax.devcenter.cql.ui.jobs.ExecuteCqlScriptJobChangeAdapter-java.lang.NumberFormatException: Zero length BigInteger

Comment: If you solve, mark my answer as solution

Answer (score 1):

Ok.

As you can see [here](http://www.outsystems.com/help/servicestudio/9.0/Integrating_with_other_systems/Web_Services/XML_Data_Types_to_OutSystems_Data_Types.htm) positiveInteger attributes in the webservice are mapped to Text in OutSystems. I'd say that when you are calling this webservice you are not passing any values for these attributes when a value is probably expected in the other side. If you need to send a null instead of "" or "0" then [check this topic](http://www.outsystems.com/help/servicestudio/9.0/Designing_Actions/Input_Parameter_Properties.htm) and see the Send Default Value property for the input parameters of consumed SOAP web services.

Comment: I have checked data inserted into the table from service it is not passed as null. I have changed the type of column to int and tested it. There was no error on select but when I pass the data as 100 (int) the data that is entered over there is 1120403456, help me to solve this please

Comment: I have fixed it by passing value's data type as decimal. It was my mistake for passing value as float for a column with data type as decimal.

Comment: Good moorning, decimal doesn't approximate the number so maybe it is the  reason.
It's awesome that you have solve that problem.